# Can LASD file be used as input in Classify Point Cloud Using Trained Model tool in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, lidar, las, point-cloud, lasd

I have 400+ LAS files and also a LASD data set derived from all of them. The LAS files together are somewhere above 50GB in size. The LASD is only ~800 KB. I take it, then, that the LASD obviously does not contain all of the original data, but rather references it in some way. I was told, however, that the LASD can be used as a single input file in the Classify Point Cloud Using Trained Model tool. But the fact that the points are seemingly not present in the LASD file suggests otherwise to me. I am also receiving an Error 999999 message when I run the classify tool, and suspect it is related to my use of LASD as input. ArcGIS recognizes the LASD as an acceptable file type, however, and allows the tool to run with it.